# C# Soap 1.2 WebService

Tags: c#, soap, httpwebrequest, content-type

I am having an issue when calling an external third-part soap web service: the error am getting is 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.'(from client), but the problem is when I do call using SoapUI 5.4.0 (on the same PC under the same user) it runs fine. The code works on any other web services.

Can someone give me any idea?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program

/// Soap WebService call

    public static void Execute()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest();
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
        NewMethod(soapEnvelopeXml);

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
                Console.WriteLine("Done!");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    }

    private static void NewMethod(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml)
    {
            soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(xml: @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:out=""http://www.test.com/test/Services/Outage""><soap:Header/><soap:Body><out:GetLocations/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");

    }



    /// Create a soap webrequest to [Url]
    public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
    {
         HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://test:557/OutageService.svc");

        webRequest.ContentType = @"application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        return webRequest;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Execute();

    }

 }
}
```

And SoapUI 5.4.0 (I've changed the domain name to 'test')

XML

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:out="http://www.test.com/test/Services/Outage">
<soap:Header/>
 <soap:Body>
   <out:GetLocations/>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

RAW

```
POST http://test:557/OutageService.svc HTTP/1.1
 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
 Content-Type:   application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://www.test.com/test/Services/Outage/IOutageService/GetLocations"
 Content-Length: 390
 Host: test:557
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

Respond

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 155883
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 12 Mar 2018 16:09:46 GMT

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/so.........
```

[SoapUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ0GI.png)

Comment: Have you considered using the built in framework tools for consuming soap services rather than rolling your own XML? Should be as simple as "Add Service Reference" on project node, then entering in the WSDL.

Comment: Two things:  1) A 500 Internal Server Error is really your 3rd party's problem, not yours. 2) That said, obviously there's a difference in the way you are sending parameters between the two clients. You should iron that out. The suggestion above is the way I would go.

Comment: Thank you for your respond but I cannot see the difference between my code and SoapUI client. Why it works on SoapUI?

Comment: I would try running the request through fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and checking to make sure your http headers are the same in addition to your content.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Broom! 
I've done a few tests using fiddler and I've got the following message:

```
          <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"   xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/fault</a:Action></s:Header><s:Body><s:Fault><s:Code><s:Value>s:Sender
 </s:Value><s:Subcode><s:Value>                                                  
   a:ActionMismatch</s:Value></s:Subcode></s:Code><s:Reason><s:Text  xml:lang="en-US">
 The SOAP action specified on the       message, '"http://www.test.com/test/Services/Outage/IOutageService/GetLocations"',
   does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'http://www.test.com/test/Services/Outage/IOutageService/GetLocations'. 

 </s:Text></s:Reason><s:Detail><a:ProblemHeaderQName>a:Action</a:ProblemHeaderQName></s:Detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

so in my code I've changed

```
private static void NewMethod(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml)
{
        soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(xml: @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:out=""http://www.test.com/test/Services/Outage""><soap:Header/><soap:Body><out:GetLocations/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");

}
```

to the following

```
soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(xml: @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:out=""http://www.test.com/test/Services/Outage""><soap:Header xmlns:wsa=""http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing""><wsa:Action>http://www.test.com/test/Services/Outage/IOutageService/GetLocations</wsa:Action></soap:Header><soap:Body><out:GetLocations/></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");
```

Which defines the Action in Content-Type

```
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://www.test.com/test/Services/Outage/IOutageService/GetLocations"
```

And then I've changed Content-Type in WebRequest

```
var contentString =  @"application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=""http://www.test/test/Services/Outage/IOutageService/GetLocations""";
        webRequest.ContentType = contentString;
```

And the code receives the xml from web service. 
Just need to be aware of double quotes!!!!